# How can I select the relevant data by group in the data frame if the 1st row by group satisfy specific condition in R?

Tags: r

The data set has 3 columns-the 1st column is "id", the 2nd column is "treatment", and the 3rd column is "time". The 2nd column is a binary variable. Now, I want to extract the data by group based on the rule as follows.

1)Within each id, as long as the first row satisfy the condition of (time=1 and treatment=0),then we select the whole group data across id.

To sum, the expected data set should look like this,

```
 id     treatment   time
1   0   1
1   0   2
1   0   3
1   0   4
1   0   5
1   0   6
1   0   7
1   NA  8
1   0   9
1   0   10
3   0   1
3   NA  2
3   1   3
3   1   4
3   1   5
3   1   6
3   1   7
3   NA  8
3   1   9
3   1   10
5   0   1
5   NA  2
5   0   3
5   0   4
5   0   5
5   0   6
5   0   7
5   0   8
5   0   9
5   0   10
```

The original data set with errors is structured as follows,

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), treatment = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 
NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
    6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")->dataframe
```

Thank you!

Comment: I clicked on the icon of voted up, but it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `filter` on the `first` value in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

dataframe %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(first(time) == 1 && first(LEP) == 0) %>%
  ungroup

#      id gender   LEP  time
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1      0     0     1
# 2     1      0     0     2
# 3     1      0     0     3
# 4     1      0     0     4
# 5     1      0     0     5
# 6     1      0     0     6
# 7     1      0     0     7
# 8     1      0    NA     8
# 9     1      0     0     9
#10     1      0     0    10
# … with 20 more rows
```

---

Another approach in base R would be to extract only the first row of each `id` and keep only `id` which has `LEP = 0` and `time = 1`.

```
subset(dataframe, id %in% id[!duplicated(id) & LEP == 0 & time == 1])
```